# Does Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu phone work in United States? Can i sign up with att or verizon or?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Want to buy Meizu Pro5 Ubuntu phone.  Can't find any info about what United States wireless phones companies i can sign up with.  Is there a user manual for the phone?

Comment: You could try looking on [Will My Phone Work](http://willmyphonework.net) which is a tool to check this, and does list Meizu phones

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Looks like the phone will work at slower data speeds on att, sprint, tmobile

Comment: Pretty much no Ubuntu phones will work on Verizon or Sprint (or any providers which buy bandwidth from them), as only GSM is supported at the moment. As Verizon and Sprint are still CDMA, they won't generally be usable.

Answer (score 1):

I have the phone and tried using it on all major usa wireless operators. trying to activate on sprint or verizon based MVNO's will result in invalid IMEI error. It works fine with H2O an ATT based MVNO and I even got a 4g connection with them.  I was also able to activate it on TPO a t-mobile based MVNO and got 3g.  Due to not supporting all the bands used by these carriers coverage is much worse then with my Nexus 5 on the same networks.